# How to organize plot order in facet wrap

Tags: r, facet, facet-wrap

I am trying to order the plots in a facet wrap differently, based on age (<30, 30-50, and >50). I have been trying to create a factor to put them in the order I want, as I have seen in some answered questions on stack, but it seems to turn all ages into 'NA'. The code provided in these answers isn't working for me.

I have tried creating a factor with different levels, but that essentially deletes the ages from the data frame.

```
glimpse(zbias)
Observations: 9,615
Variables: 5
$ ID       <chr> "5129615189", "5128877943", "5126775994", "5126598863", "5124909744…
$ Age      <chr> "30-50 years", "> 50 years", "30-50 years", "30-50 years", "> 50 ye…
$ Country  <chr> "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Albania", "Ireland",   "Denmark", "Belgi…
$ vignette <fct> v01_z, v01_z, v01_z, v01_z, v01_z, v01_z, v01_z, v01_z, v01_z, v01_…
$ stdbias  <dbl> 0.2716474, 0.2716474, 0.2716474, 0.6791186, 0.2716474, 0.2716474, 0…

zbais <- stdbias

zbias$Age <- factor(zbias$Age, levels=c("< 30","30-50","> 50"), ordered=TRUE)

#Plot standard z-scores by age group
ggplot(zbias)+
geom_density(aes(stdbias))+
 facet_wrap(~Age, scales = "free_x")+
  labs(x="Standard Bias", y="Density")

 dput(head(zbias))
structure(list(ID = c("5129615189", "5128877943", "5126775994", 
"5126598863", "5124909744", "5122047758"), Age = c("30-50 years", 
"> 50 years", "30-50 years", "30-50 years", "> 50 years", "30-50 years"
), Country = c("France", "Spain", "Spain", "Albania", "Ireland", 
"Denmark"), vignette = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label =    c("v01_z", 
"v02_z", "v03_z", "v04_z", "v05_z", "v06_z", "v07_z", "v08_z", 
"v09_z", "v10_z", "v11_z", "v12_z", "v13_z", "v14_z", "v15_z"
), class = "factor"), stdbias = c(0.271647421614958, 0.271647421614958, 
0.271647421614958, 0.679118554037396, 0.271647421614958, 0.271647421614958
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am getting the three plots in the facet wrap, however 30-50 and > 50 are in the wrong positions. So I would like them to be in ascending order by age. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide the `dput(head(zbias))` so your question is **reproducible**

Comment: the problem may be in the line where you are creating the factor  - the levels do no correspond to the elements in zbias$Age.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the line where you create factors. Your new levels, e.g. `"< 30"`, are not matching the characters in the original column, e.g. `"< 30 years"`. In case you want the shorter version you need to get rid of the `" years"` first. You can use `gsub()` for this. See this example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# your groups
age_groups <- c("< 30","30-50","> 50")

# sample data
zbias <- tibble(stdbias=1:99,Age=rep(c("< 30 years", "30-50 years", "> 50 years"),33))

# creating new categories
zbias <- zbias %>%
  mutate(age_cat=gsub(" years","",Age)) %>%
  mutate(age_cat=factor(age_cat,levels=age_groups))

# plotting
ggplot(zbias)+
  geom_density(aes(stdbias))+
  facet_wrap(~age_cat, scales = "free_x")+
  labs(x="Standard Bias", y="Density")
```

Does this solve your problem?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you pointed out a very (now) obvious flaw, and it was fixed! Thank you!